# How to ensure the type of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MyList<E> {

}
```

In the example above, how could I ensure that E is of a certain class when a "MyList" object is created?

Comment: `E extends MyClass`

Comment: Why make it generic if you only accept one type?

Comment: you need to restrict `E` to the class/interface you want to bound it to, like `E extends B`

Comment: I support what @Mat is suggesting. If you know that `E` is of a certain type, then the class is no longer generic...

Comment: @Mat I am making a game and want to create a list that will only be able to hold GameObjects and I don't want to use an ArrayList because I need to have methods in it that are specific to GameObject.

Comment: @JackHipson300 why don't you use an `ArrayList<GameObject>` then? Or use one internally in your `MyList` class, then `MyList` doesn't need to be generic.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure that E is of a certain class"? Should `E` *always* be of one specified class? If yes then what is the point of having generic type here? This looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Show us your real code.

Comment: `public class MyList extends ArrayList<GameObject> { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `MyList` object for say integers, you do this:

```
MyList<Integer> myList = new MyList<>();
```

I see in your comments, you wanted to create it for type `GameObject`, you can do it the same way:

```
MyList<GameObject> myList = new MyList<>();
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @Pshemo, what makes you say that? OP is asking about creating a `MyList` object for a given type. That's what this answers

Comment: Because that still allows you to set different types for `MyList` like `MyList<String>` `MyList<Car>` and so on. It is not limited to one specific type (not ensuring that it will be used with only one specific type). But it is true that question is not very clear so I may be misunderstanding OP.

Comment: @Pshemo, this is true. I was initially thinking the question was about the generic nature of the class, but I see the OP was asking about creating and instance of this class, which is what lead me to believe that this is what he was asking about

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using generic bound like below.

```
class MyList<E extends YourClass> {

}
```

For example :

```
class MyList<E extends Number> {
}
```

For above example, MyList only allow passing `Number` or its subtype (`Integer, Double etc`)

So if you try to create object like below.

```
MyList<Integer> list = new MyList<>(); // This will works fine as Integer is subclass of Number.

MyList<String> list = new MyList<>(); // This will give you compilation error as String is not a subclass of number.
```